# How do I communicate between Arduino board and Intel Edison Arduino board using XBee S2?

Tags: arduino-uno, iot, xbee, intel-edison

I have an [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) board and an XBee S2 device on it. I can identify my Arduino Uno board is transmitting data from XBee S2 by seeing the tx LED, but I am not clear how to receive data on the [Intel Edison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Edison) Arduino setup board (XBee S2 is also connected to the Intel Edison board).

I am not clear how the Arduino shield board for Intel Edison is supporting UART to Tx/Rx data through XBee S2. How do I actually write XBee S2 code? Is it only a serial UART communication?

Comment: Any reference is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I did this coding using API mode and AT mode for xbee ,received input to edison using canonical receive uart program.